# Input POST data into MySQL table not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, cloud9

having some trouble inputting user data from input fields into my MySQL table. Here's the code. Any help appreciated.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
                    First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
                    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName" /> <br />
                    Email: <input type="email" name="email" /> <br />
                    Username: <input type="text" name="uName" /> <br />
                    Password: <input type="password" name="pw" /> <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="register" />
            </form>
            <br>
            <form action="login.php">
               Already have an account?
                    <input type="submit" value="Login Here" />
            </form>
    </div>
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["register"])){
     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $lName = $_POST["lName"];
     $email = $_POST["email"];
     $uName = $_POST["uName"];
     $pw = $_POST["pw"];

     $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, $name, $lname, $email, $uName, $pw, null)";

     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: (Free) Pro tip: Don't go live with this, until you use both a prepared statement and `password_hash()`. You **will** get hacked.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: This is still very basic implementaion, I'm very new to MySQL and am having trouble even getting the data into the database.  Hashing and whatnot is next on the list.

Comment: you should use single qoute around your variable name in the query, and i think you are ok after that

Comment: BTW, too late for me to answer as it's been marked as a dupe, but your variable name $lName is being inserted as $iname. This is likely the cause of your issues.